How to use MathType to insert the indicator function 1 into Microsoft Word
I'm using MathType to insert the indicator function 1 into Microsoft Word. It looks like the following:
double stroke digit 1
But I didn't find it in MathType. How can I type it by MathType?

This character is only available in the MathType add-in for Microsoft 365 & Office 2021, not in MathType 7 (the desktop standalone app).
In order to introduce it in MathType add-in for Microsoft 365 & Office 2021, go to the 'Insert special character' command and search the unicode: 1D7D9
The indicator function 1 will appear and you will be able to insert it.
Image guide
